# upload file to network drive in php

Tags: php, file-upload, iis-7, network-drive

php script for uploading file to mapped network drive is not working . Following are the php script:

```
$newfilename = "something.wav";
$path  = 'Y:\\uploaded\\'.$newfilename;
copy($_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'], $path);
```

I have also check permission for network drive folder.I have Y drive mapped to the network drive(10.4.4.32) d drive within uploaded folder. It have full control permission. I have tried following path for network drive:

- Y:\uploaded\
- \\10.4.4.32\d$\uploaded\
- move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'], $path);

But, It works on local drive like:

- d:\uploaded\
  The file is uploaded in local drive but could not uploaded in network drive. I have used php 5.3 and IIS 7 for application

Errors Showed:
**Warning: copy(\10.4.4.32\d$\uploaded\test.wav): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp\upload.php on line 107**

I have allow permission of full control in the properties of the uploaded folder for EVERYONE user. Is there any other permission , I should fixed.

Comment: Have you already tried with move_uploaded_file()?

Comment: ya, I have just tried, not working..

Comment: "It does not work" - great explanation of your problem, I'm contacting Charles Xavier to help me figure out what "does not work" means for you.

Comment: I explained that it is uploaded to the local drive but not in network drive and there isn't showing any error while file not uploaded....

Answer (score 0):

First, check if `copy()` returns false. This indicates that there is really an error.

Then, enable the `track_errors` directive in your php.ini, as well as `display_errors` and `error_reporting` to the highest level.
When `track_errors` is activated (and you restarted your webserver), use the following line after the copy:

```
var_dump($php_errormsg, error_get_last());
```

This should give you a better hint about the problem.

---

Also make sure that if you're using `safe_mode` and `open_basedir`, the path you're moving to is allowed.

Comment: shows Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\php2693.tmp' to '\\10.4.4.32\d$\uploaded\test.wav' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp\upload.php on line 104
string(145) "move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\php2693.tmp' to '\\10.4.4.32\d$\uploaded\test.wav'" array(4) { ["type"]=> int(2) ["message"]=> string(145) "move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\php2693.tmp' to '\\10.4.4.32\d$\uploaded\test.wav'" ["file"]=> string(47) "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp\upload.php" ["line"]=> int(104) }

Comment: are you sure that the folder name is `d$` with the `$` in there?

Answer (score 0):

network drive may not work for neither apache nor php , so use this $path = "\\machine-name\share_path\";

set up an user account on BOTH computer such as  user : ApacheUser

go to services and click  Apache , and use the account just created to logon (second tab) the Apache service of source computer

restart the apache service

then it should work now